# Nuxt-i18n: use path to public (static) folder with a locale prefix

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, internationalization, locale, nuxt-i18n

I'm running into problems trying to serve images from the public folder when there's a locale prefix in the url (see screenshot). Everything works fine with the default locale since the strategy is 'prefix_except_default'. How can I fix this?

My img tag looks like this: `<img class="w-72" src="logo.jpg" alt="">`

[image]

Comment: Hey, did you ever find a solution to this? Encountering something similar

Comment: yes, it worked when I changed the path to ```src="/logo.jpg"```